# Application that would set default application for file types

Tags: file-types

Do you know of any application that could define the application for opening different file types?
For example, setting a default application that would open .reg files.
Or if there is not any then what do I do to set it?

Comment: which operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinXP and below;

```
Tools, Folder Options, File Associations
```

Win Vista and above;

```
Start, Control Pannel, Default Programs,
"Associate a file type or protocol with a program"
```